# screen search and pyautogui image issues ( 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape' )

Tags: python, pyautogui

So I have been having issues with both screen search and pyautogui.

Heres the screen search

```
from screen_search import *

search = Search("windows.jpg")

pos = search.imagesearch()

if pos[0] != -1:
    print("position : ", pos[0], pos[1])
    pyautogui.moveTo(pos[0], pos[1])
else:
    print("image not found")
```

**Full Error:**

```
  File "d:stuff", line 5, in <module>
    pos = search.imagesearch()
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\screen_search\screen_search.py", line 35, in imagesearch
    template.shape[::-1]
```

And I have been getting this error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
I decided to switch to pyautogui and did this.

```
from pyautogui import *

def main():

    print(locateOnScreen('windows.jpg', confidence = 0.5))

main()
```

I still get a error.

```
Failed to read windows.jpg because file is missing, has improper permissions, or is an unsupported or invalid format.
```

Comment: Please copy paste the full error message in your question.
It is important to see exactly which line provoked the error.

Comment: This is still not the complete error message. But perhaps it will help to identify the error.

So far I didn't have time to read screen_search the documentation screen_search of screensearch, but are you sure, that jpg is a valid file format (.jpg files are image files with a lossy compression, I would have expected, that only files with lossless compression are permitted like for example .png files.)

Will go through the spec, make some tests and come back later.

Comment: One thing, that is also worth noticing is, that you are using screen_search (which has only one released version ( https://pypi.org/project/screen-search/#history ) on 14th october 2019 together with python 3.9 which was first released in october 2020 ( https://devguide.python.org/#status-of-python-branches )

This means this combination has never been tested by the devs. It is even unlikely, that python 3.8 and screen-search have ever been tested, as python 3.8's first release coincides with the release date of screen-search.
Even worse screensearch doesn't seem to have unit tests

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**

Very probably, the file `windows.jpg` is not located in python's current working directory, but there could be other reasons.

Look at the code snippet at the end of my answer, execute it and you will probably be able to identify the problem:

**Long answer:**
The problem, that you encounter is, that the error message, that screen_search is providing is rather useless and not very helpful.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xxxx.py", line 14, in <module>
    main()
  File "xxxx.py", line 10, in main
    pos = search.imagesearch()
  File "..../lib/python3.9/site-packages/screen_search/screen_search.py", line 35, in imagesearch
    template.shape[::-1]
```

The message of your second code snippet however is a little more constructive:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xxx.py", line 13, in <module>
    main()
  File "xxx.py", line 9, in main
    pos = locateOnScreen(fname, confidence = 0.5)
  File ".../lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 175, in wrapper
    return wrappedFunction(*args, **kwargs)
  File ".../lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 213, in locateOnScreen
    return pyscreeze.locateOnScreen(*args, **kwargs)
  File ".../lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyscreeze/__init__.py", line 360, in locateOnScreen
    retVal = locate(image, screenshotIm, **kwargs)
  File ".../lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyscreeze/__init__.py", line 340, in locate
    points = tuple(locateAll(needleImage, haystackImage, **kwargs))
  File ".../lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyscreeze/__init__.py", line 197, in _locateAll_opencv
    needleImage = _load_cv2(needleImage, grayscale)
  File ".../lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyscreeze/__init__.py", line 160, in _load_cv2
    raise IOError("Failed to read %s because file is missing, "
OSError: Failed to read windows.jpg because file is missing, has improper permissions, or is an unsupported or invalid format
```

It tells you, that
**OSError: Failed to read windows.jpg because file is missing, has improper permissions, or is an unsupported or invalid format**

So what you have to check is whether the file `windows.jpg` really exists (in the current working directory as you specified a relative path)

If it really exists check that the file can be read and if this is also true, check that the file is really a jpeg file and can be opened with an image viewing application.

I guess, that the file exists, is readable and that it is indeed a jpeg file, but that it is not located in the present working directory.

```
import os
import sys
from PIL import Image

from screen_search import *

fname = "windows.jpg"
current_working_directory = os.getcwd()
print("My current working directory is",current_working_directory)

absolute_fname = os.path.realpath(fname)
print("the image file name is", fname)
print("the absolute file name", os.path.realpath(fname))
if not os.path.exists(absolute_fname):
    print("cannot find file", absolute_fname)
    sys.exit(1)
if not os.path.isfile(absolute_fname):
    print(absolute_fname, "exists, but is no file")
    sys.exit(1)
if not os.access(absolute_fname, os.R_OK):
    print("the file", absolute_fname, "is not readable")
    sys.exit(1)
try:
    img = Image.open(fname)
except OSError:
    print("The readable file", absolute_fname, "doesn't seem to contain valid data")
    sys.exit(1)

search = Search(absolute_fname)

pos = search.imagesearch()

if pos[0] != -1:
    print("position : ", pos[0], pos[1])
    pyautogui.moveTo(pos[0], pos[1])
else:
    print("image not found")
```

**Addendum for Windows Users:**

Windows has the very annoying habit of not display file extensions in the windows explorer. this is confusing.

So with windows default settings.
If a jpg file is displayed as `windows` its real name is `windows.jpg`
if it is displayed as `windows.jpg` its real name will be `windows.jpg.jpg`

To stop this annoying windows behavior I suggest do setup windows explorer to display file extensions. ( https://www.howtogeek.com/205086/beginner-how-to-make-windows-show-file-extensions/ )

Answer (score 0):

I change a few things and its works now idk why it worked but it did

```
windows = Image.open(r"C:\Users\kaleb\Pictures\Photo recognition albion\windows.png")
```

Then instead of using windows.png I just used windows and it seams to work now

Comment: Windows by default is hiding the file extensions, 

Ah I see, what happened if renaming from window.jpg to windows fixed the problem ist, htat in reality you renamed the file from `windows.jpg.jpg` to `windows.jpg`.

or if it was a png probably from:
`windows.jpg.png` to `windows.png`
What you probably did is create a file, that was called windows.jpg.jpg.

You might look at https://www.howtogeek.com/205086/beginner-how-to-make-windows-show-file-extensions/ to enable the file extension.

Comment: I added ab addendum to my answer mentioning the pitfall, that you were victim off.

Comment: Nah it was just named windows, but I just added the Image.open to get the file instead of asking the function locate on screen to do it

Comment: You're sure? Did you enable the displaying of file extensions on your windows PC as I suggested (with https://www.howtogeek.com/205086/beginner-how-to-make-windows-show-file-extensions/ )

Comment: This is strange for everything works even with your original code.

Did you at least  try my suggested  answer to see what output message you get?

I don't have a window system, but everything works for me.

Just post the output you get if you try

Comment: Nope idk why it just sometimes works and then doesnt it works about 80% if the time with the new. I know it throws a error when it doesnt find the image, but I put a except in there.